# I want to restrict my webservice url accessible from any browser only it is accessbile from android app

Tags: java, php, android, web-services, url

I am using php for web services so I want to restrict that url( of Web services) from browser so if any user get to know about that url he can not access it from browser

```
String url_login="abcd.com+email+"+Email+"&pwd="+Password;
```

If Anyone write this url form browser he get message of access denied or something. Is it possible? if yes than please give your suggestions...

Comment: use Authentication header while requesting URL

Comment: you could use user-agent header parameter to understand the source of the request

Comment: which type authentication?

Comment: please give some example... @Divyesh Patel

Comment: are you using any networking Library  for api request/response

Comment: i am using volley for network call @Divyesh Patel

Comment: check this: https://coderwall.com/p/f3oioq/simple-get-request-using-volley-android-basic-authentifications

Comment: can you please give me more brief about how user-agent will recognize that request comes from android app @Yogesh Patil

Comment: use POST web-services instead of GET.

Comment: I am not talking about to hide the parameters ... I am talking to restrict url from browser @rajesh

Comment: In that case you should use header authentication in webservices as suggested by @divyesh patel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a header parameter sent via browsers called User-Agent. The value of this parameter can provide you the valuable information about the place of origin of that request.

Info about user-agent from chrome dev [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent)

eg, Check the last request param
eg [image]